# Unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transactions

I received a transaction which has been unconfirmed for 36 hours with 0 confirmations. I'm relatively new to btc and having had a relatively speedy, problem free experience so far I'm not sure what to make of it.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks.

https://blockchain.info/tx/751bd6c180fac5c1b54ba428d2b4416a13ecefd978193e5dc8138f5b0de56f86

Comment: It looks like the transaction doesn't have fees. That will make things take much longer.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction doesn't seem to have propagated through the network, meaning that not many nodes know about it.  I personally am not sure what to do about that, if there is anything you can do about it.

You could try having the person who sent you the coins restore their wallet from a backup, rescan the blockchain, and send you the coins again.  I think you might be able to get them through like that.  I would recommend having them put a transaction fee on it, though.  That should help it get put into a block quickly.